# Converting grid_code values to lat and longs or UTMs using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1

I have made a text file from raster to points via a DEM in ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 where I have inserted values in an another column that I want to display. Next to point ID is `grid_code`, which I believe substitutes for `lat` and `long`.

How do I convert these grid_code values(which are z-scores of the study area) to lat and longs or UTMs?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. It often helps if you can show a small sample of your data, and what you've already looked at / tried (plus what happened). Right now your question is very open-ended, so its hard to provide a useful answer without either skipping over stuff that we assume you know, or telling you stuff that is obvious to you. Can you update your question with some more background and info?

Answer (score 2):

The [Add XY Coordinates](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000032000000) tool which:

> Adds the fields POINT_X and POINT_Y to the point input features and
>   calculates their values. It also appends the POINT_Z and POINT_M
>   fields if the input features are Z- and M-enabled.

should do the trick!